# How to perform number of days calculation in Django related field query

Tags: django

I have 2 models:

```
class Assets(models.Model):
    assetMake = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)
    assetModel = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)

class Maintenance(models.Model):
    assetID = models.ForeignKey(Assets, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateRequested = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateCompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

I want to have a view that displays all the Assets in order of when they were last maintained (`dateCompleted`). Which this accomplishes below:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Assets.objects.annotate(
    last_modified=Max('maintenance__dateCompleted')
).order_by('-last_modified')
```

But how can I calculate the number of days from `dateCompleted` to now so that I can display this value as well.
Something like:

```
Assets.objects.annotate(
     last_modified=Max('maintenance__dateCompleted'),
     days = ((timezone.now() - maintenance__dateCompleted).days
).order_by('-last_modified')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) with [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper)

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models.fields import DurationField

assets_annotate = Assets.objects.annotate(
    days_dif = ExpressionWrapper(
        timezone.now() - F('maintenance__dateCompleted'), 
        output_field = DurationField()
    )
)
```

Then you can get days count with `assets_annotate[0].days_dif.days`

Comment: I think this is close, but it is returning 'expected string or bytes-like object'

Comment: I gues we need to add `ExpressionWrapper`, watch update.

Comment: That is outputting a day count of 0 no matter the date. I think we are close here.